# keyboard not responding to access Windows 7 startup options

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am having numerous problems with my computer after upgrading to Win 7 from XP.  My immediate proble is my keyboard is not recognized after BIOS booting to allow me to access the Windows startup options.  There is not a problem with the keyboard because I have tried an OS2 keyboard and still incur the problem.  During BIOS boot the keyboard works fine (I can enter BIOS with the delete key and perform changes if needed) and after Windows starts it is functional again.  I can force a Windows to boot to the repair options through msconfig, but once the system gets there I still cannot choose an option because the keyboard is not functioning.

As I said before, I have numerous problems since the upgrade but until I can resolve this issue I can't even troubleshoot the othe issues.

Comment: Is the keyboard connected via a PS/2 connector?  Or a USB connector?  And what's an "OS2 keyboard" when it is at home?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but in BIOS, try turning  off the Plug and Play OS option.