# Laptop keyboard unresponsive in Windows Boot Manager

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, keyboard, multi-boot

I'm trying to fix a problem on a laptop and I hit a dead wall.

Upon getting to the Windows Boot Manager screen, normally I press up and select Windows 7, however no keys work anymore there, not even ENTER when Windows XP is highlighted.

The laptop keyboard is not broken - by holding DEL on boot I can get into the BIOS and arrow keys work fine there (I can only change the date), and in Windows XP all keys work fine as well, but not in the Windows Boot Manager.

Also tried PgDn/PgUp, Ctrl+P/Ctrl+N, +/- and 8/2 as alternatives to go up or down. F8,TAB and ESC also don't work in Windows Boot Manager.

Any idea whats going on or how this could be fixed?

Also: The arrow keys **normally** stopped responding after 3-4 seconds, not the whole 15 second timer. I just kinda dealt with it.

It's an older Dell laptop - BIOS dated 2008

Almost exact same issue that didnt get solved:
[keyboard not responding to access Windows 7 startup options](https://superuser.com/questions/373464/keyboard-not-responding-to-access-windows-7-startup-options?rq=1)

Comment: As I recall earlier versions of Windows Boot Manager did not support USB keyboards. Could this be your problem?

Comment: I don't have a USB keyboard, just the laptop itself.

Comment: Try an external usb keyboard...